# Why is there no hint/hover info about Status Menu icons?

Tags: 18.04, icons, statusbar

There are some icons on the Ubuntu 18.04.1 Status Menu (e.g. between Power and Settings) whose purpose isn't clear, as there is no hover/hint information if you move the mouse over them (which you do for say the left-hand shortcut/favourites bar and Chrome browser tabs).

Is this a bug or deliberate choice to hide information from users?

e.g. It's taken me months to realise that one of those icons stops the screen from rotating when I let my laptop tilt over.

Comment: Asking here, at Ask Ubuntu is one way to learn: https://askubuntu.com/q/1063775/480481 :-)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I enable tool-tips for GNOME Status menu buttons to understand functionality of one specific button?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1063775/how-do-i-enable-tool-tips-for-gnome-status-menu-buttons-to-understand-functional)

Comment: It's possible that designers decided to not include tooltips, if that's what is meant by "hint/hover", to avoid "clutter".